# what's the difference between []int{} and []int in go?

Tags: go

here are two different definations in go, but what's the difference?
I have tried the following:

```
func main() {
    var test1 []int
    test2 := []int{}

    if test1 == nil {
        fmt.Println(1)
    }
    if test2 == nil {
        fmt.Println(2)
    }
    fmt.Println("test1:", test1)
    fmt.Println("test2:", test2)
}
```

and this is the output:

```
1
test1: []
test2: []
```

but why the test1 is nil but the other is not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By itself, `[]int` is a spelling for the type *slice of `int`*.

In:

```
var test1 []int
```

the `[]int` supplies the type for the variable `test1`.  The line as a whole supplies *no* value, so `test1` is initialized to the [*zero value*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of type `[]int`.  The zero value of this is `[]int(nil)`, or informally, just nil.<sup>1</sup>

In:

```
test2 := []int{}
```

the `[]int` supplies the type for the brace-enclosed initializer list.  That is, `{}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals): an open brace, followed by a list of elements—in this case empty—followed by a close brace.  The remainder of the line—the `:=` and the variable name on the left—represent a [*short variable declaration*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).  This gives variable `test2` the *type* `[]int`, and the *value* produced by the empty list.

The value produced by the empty list is, in this case, an empty slice of `int`: one with an empty<sup>2</sup> backing store, a length of zero, and a capacity of zero.

That's why `test1` is nil but `test2` is not: `test1` holds the zero value, which for any slice type, is `nil` (after `nil` gets converted to that type anyway).  Meanwhile `test2` holds the three-part slice header that covers the zero-length backing array created by the compound literal.

A nil slice—which is a bit of sloppy phrasing: it means *a value of type slice-of-`T` whose actual value is `[]T(nil)` instead of some three-part slice header*—can often be *used as* an empty (length-zero) slice of the same type.  In particular, `for i := range x` and `x = append(x, newElement)` both handle `x == nil` "nicely": they treat it the same way as they would an empty slice.  The `fmt` routines that print slices do this as well.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>`nil` by itself is *untyped*.  See the first mention of `nil` in [the Go specification, under the section **Variables**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables).

<sup>2</sup>It's not possible to tell, at least without using `unsafe.Pointer` or similar, whether Go actually allocated any storage for the backing array.  Any operation you do on the slice to give it some capacity, so that you can put some values into memory somewhere, will or could just allocate a *new* backing array.  There are some tricks with the `unsafe` package for peeking into the Go runtime, but in general, you don't need to do that, and should not.

<sup>3</sup>By contrast, `map` types don't play quite as nicely.  If `x` is—to speak informally—a slice that may be nil, and `m` is a map that may be nil, we can do:

```
x = append(x, newElem)
```

but we cannot do:

```
m[key] = newElem
```

We have to first check whether `m` is nil and if so, allocate an empty map:

```
if m == nil {
    m = make(...) // put in the right type here
}
m[key] = newElem
```

So it's relatively common to use:

```
var x []T
m := map[string]T{}
```

right next to each other, because `x` will behave well and `m` won't.

Comment: Regarding note 2)  There is a supported way to get a pointer to a slice's backing array: `reflect.ValueOf(slice).Pointer()`.  It turns out that all slices allocated with zero capacity share the same pointer ([example program](https://play.golang.org/p/z46X3cpQufu)).   It follows that allocating a slice with zero capacity does not allocate memory.  In fact, a zero size allocation in the runtime uses the address of [this variable](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a3dc6da6d6d25666d24bab293c0990d1b07bb798/src/runtime/malloc.go#L825).

Comment: @iLoveReflection: Technically, that gives you a pointer to an *element* in the backing array. For instance, if the slice has backing array `var backing [4]T`, but was adjusted forward 2 steps by reslicing, you get the address of backing[2] instead of backing[0]. (I was experimenting with this yesterday.) We're also told that we cannot take the address one past the last element of an array. If an array A has size 1, we can get &A[0] but not &A[1]. So if the backing array has size *zero*, we can't even inspect &A[0], at least not officially. But ...

Comment: ... all that said, if we're unsafe enough, or just look at the source, we find: Yes, the current implementation [does just what you said](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a3dc6da6d6d25666d24bab293c0990d1b07bb798/src/runtime/malloc.go#L895). :-) (BTW, the reason I was experimenting was to see if there was an efficient way to write a test: "do slices S1 and S2 potentially overlap?" The answer is that there is, if we're allowed to be unsafe, but it's not as useful as we might like.)

Answer (score 1):

It is the difference between nil and empty slice. In golang, if you declare a variable without a value, it’s value becomes the zero value of the variable type. The zero value of the array is nil. Not empty slice. Empty slice can be generated with make function or shorty the second method that you have used for test2